# octave mann-whitney/u_test p-value confusion

Tags: statistics, octave, p-value

I find the result of mann-whitney test confusing, and the gnu documentation didn't help me.  https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Tests.html

Here is the simple example I tried:

```
octave:1> x=[1,1,1,1,1]
x =

   1   1   1   1   1

octave:2> y=[2,2,2,2,2,2]
y =

   2   2   2   2   2   2

octave:3> [p,z]=u_test(x, y, "<>")
p =  0.0061699
z = -2.7386
octave:4> [p,z]=u_test(x, y, ">")
p =  0.0030849
z = -2.7386
```

The first u_test makes sense since at that p value, the null hypothesis is rejected, and the alternative, which is that P(x>y) != 1/2 would be accepted.

However, the second u_test would suggest that the null hypothesis is again rejected so the alternative P(x>y) > 1/2 is accepted, which doesn't make any sense to me.

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had a look at `u_test.m` and the function appears to have several bugs, thank you for discovering and reporting it.

You are right, the author has mixed up the order of the tests. It should be the other way round according to his definition (i.e. the result you're getting should be for `'<'`).

Furthermore, it seems that the calculation for `z` contains a bug too, this seems to be confirmed by a different p value when using online calculators.

Feel free to report this as a bug at the [octave bug tracker](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?group=octave) (and please link the resulting bug page back here in the comments; otherwise I'll report the bug if you'd like).

In the meantime I'll work on a patch. Thanks again.

Comment: (once you report the bug, keep an eye on it to spot the patched file :) )

Comment: hm, weird, I find the same value for z (2.73) using the formulas I found ... but two different online calculators name the same different value for it (2.65). Not sure what's happening ...

Comment: Thanks, Tasos.  Please report the bug since you are the one that found it.  I was just confused!